# What is Aut $Z \oplus Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What is Automorphism group of $Z \oplus Z$? Please give some hints. I feel it is some matrix group looking as the group as a Z module.

Comment: A matrix (and thus the function the matrix represents) is invertible iff its determinant is invertible.

Comment: Ok so 1 or -1 got upto that...so ad-bc may be plus or minus 1

Comment: Exactly. Each such matrix, and no others, represents an invertible epimorphism.

Comment: Yeah I got that is there a name for such a group? Specific one?

Comment: $\operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: It's called the general linear group of degree $2$ over $\Bbb Z$, shortened to either $GL_2(\Bbb Z)$ or $GL(\Bbb Z,2)$.